# How to call the superclass in this ATM machine game with Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to create an ATM game that uses a list of 10 accounts (from 0-9) and all are set to 100 to start. I have all the loops and menu items set up as needed in the main() function, but I think my Account Class is not set up right because when I pass arguments to the class functions I get errors. Is there a way I should be initiating an empty list in the Class to start? Or is there a different mistake I made in the main() function?

Here is the error I get when choosing menu item 1 to get the balance:

```
  File "/Users/Beadog/PycharmProjects/M08_12.3/gameATMMachine.py", line 82, in getBalance
    return format(self.__balance, ".2f")
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_Account__balance'
```

And here is the full code:

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, id = 0, balance = 100):
        self.__id = id
        self.__balance = balance

    def getId(self):
        return self.__id

    def getBalance(self):
        return format(self.__balance, ".2f")

    def setID(self, id):
        self.__id = id

    def setBalance(self, balance):
        self.__balance = balance

    def withdrawal(self, withdrawalAmount):
        if withdrawalAmount < self.__balance:
            self.__balance -= withdrawalAmount
        else:
            print("Insuficient Funds.")

    def deposit(self, depositAmount):
        self.__balance += depositAmount


def main():
    accounts = []
    for i in range(10):
        accounts.append(Account(i, 100))

    while True:
        id = eval(input("Enter account ID: "))

        if id >= 0 and id <= 9:

            print()
            print("Main menu")
            print("1: check balance")
            print("2: withdraw")
            print("3: deposit")
            print("4: exit")
            print()

            menuChoice = eval(input("Enter a choice: "))
            print()

            while menuChoice != 4:
                if menuChoice == 1:
                    balance = Account.getBalance(id)
                    print("The balance is ", balance)
                    print()
                    print("Main menu")
                    print("1: check balance")
                    print("2: withdraw")
                    print("3: deposit")
                    print("4: exit")
                    print()
                    menuChoice = eval(input("Enter a choice: "))
                    print()

                elif menuChoice == 2:
                    withdrawalAmount = eval(input("Enter withdrawal amount: "))
                    Account.withdrawal(id, withdrawalAmount)
                    print()
                    print("Main menu")
                    print("1: check balance")
                    print("2: withdraw")
                    print("3: deposit")
                    print("4: exit")
                    print()
                    menuChoice = eval(input("Enter a choice: "))
                    print()
                elif menuChoice == 3:
                    depositAmount = eval(input("Enter deposit amount: "))
                    Account.deposit(id, depositAmount)
                    print()
                    print("Main menu")
                    print("1: check balance")
                    print("2: withdraw")
                    print("3: deposit")
                    print("4: exit")
                    print()
                    menuChoice = eval(input("Enter a choice: "))
                    print()
                else:
                    menuChoice = eval(input(("Please enter a valid menu choice (1-4): ")))
                    print()
        else:
            print("Account ID must be a number between 0 and 9. Please try again.")
            print()

main()
```

Comment: question edited to include error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: change lines like this:

```
balance = Account.getBalance(id)
```

to this:

```
balance = accounts[id].getBalance()
```

---

**Long answer**:

You seem to misunderstand how python classes work - what's a *class* and what's an *instance of a class*. Let me correct a few of these misconceptions that your code displays.

1. With lines like `balance = Account.getBalance(id)`, you're calling the *class*, not an *instance* of the class. You know this because you're using the word `Account`, which is the name of the class, rather than a variable which is holding an instance of `Account`. In fact, earlier in your code, you created the list `accounts`, which holds 10 instances of `Account` - it's these you should be calling the function on. In other words, to call the function `getBalance()` on the `id`th instance of `Account` in the list `accounts`, you would do `accounts[id].getBalance()`.
2. The `self` parameter is *always* implied. When you call a function on an instance of a class – for example, `accounts[id].getBalance()`, the instance you used to call the function is passed as the first parameter. In this case, the parameter `self` would be `accounts[id]`. Note that you don't need to put it in the parentheses, as a result.

   - If you wanted to, you could also do `Account.getBalance(accounts[id])`, which would pass `accounts[id]` in as the `self` argument.

Comment: thank you SO MUCH! You all have been so incredibly helpful on here and I hope to have the knowledge and experience to pay it forward someday soon!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not referring to an `Account` instance when you call `getBalance()` and other methods, you are referring to the `Account` class itself. You retrieve the `Account` instance by getting it from the array where you stored it, not by passing an `id` to the `Account` method itself.

Instead of this:

```
balance = Account.getBalance(id)
```

You should be doing things like this:

```
account = accounts[id]
balance = account.getBalance()
```

Replace things like this:

```
Account.withdrawal(id, withdrawalAmount)
```

With this

```
account = accounts[id]
account.withdrawal(withdrawalAmount)
```

And so on. You were correct in the way you created and stored the `Account` instances, you just have to refer to them correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much! The prior answer did it a little differently:                     accounts[id].withdrawal(withdrawalAmount)
I see both ways work!

Comment: Glad to help! Yes they are only stylistically different. I like to do things in a more step-by-step way just to make them more explicit, whereas the prior answer does everything in one line. In most code, you are probably more likely to see it the way the prior answer did it than the way I did it. The only reason to do it my way besides illustrating things would be if you wanted to do something with the `Account` instance after calling `withdrawal` on it. Then it might make sense to store it in a variable like I did (the `account` variable), rather than writing `accounts[id]` again.

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors errors in your code. First notice that you are creating a list of accounts with:

```
accounts = []
for i in range(10):
    accounts.append(Account(i, 100))
```

but, then, you are not using it. Instead, you are calling the Accounts method using the class name `Account` instead of the the variable `accounts[i]` which holds a reference to an *istance* of the class `Account`:

```
balance = Account.getBalance(id)
```

**To make you code work, you need to change the previous line in**:

```
balance = accounts[id].getBalance()
```

Notice that I removed the `id` argument from the `getBalance()` function call (your second error). In fact, your definition of this method does not require any argument (except the one referring to the object it belong to: `self`):

```
def getBalance(self):
    return format(self.__balance, ".2f")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious.  Can u set the code correctly pls?

Comment: Hi - just the single lines of code in the 3 menu choices needed changed. So menuChoice 1 was changed to: balance = accounts[id].getBalance()  and menuChoice 2 was changed to:                     accounts[id].withdrawal(withdrawalAmount)
menuChoice 3 was changed to:                     accounts[id].deposit(depositAmount)

Comment: Hi, your code still not working perfectly.  Cause when I choose "exist " it still looping the main menu

Comment: it is supposed to ask you for a new account ID if you choose option 4. option 4 will kick you out of the inner while loop and put you back into the outer while loop which is set to always run unless you kill the program.